# Magento free product with free shipping

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce, magento-1.7

I have a product on a magento store which is free and so is the postage.

Its all set-up, I can add it to my basket go to check out select the free shipping, but once I get to payment information part, it says "Your order cannot be completed at this as there is no payment methods available for it.".

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: use zero subtotal checkout methods for free product

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@mufaddal solved this question via a comment. I'll add it as an answer just so people can see.

It was simply enabling the Zero Subtotal Checkout in the backend under Configuration - Payment Methods.

More information on Zero Subtotal Checkout can be found at the link below.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/configuration-payment-methods-zero-subtotal-checkout